# display list do not work

Tags: opengl

I have got some code like that

```
      glNewList(displist_boxy, GL_COMPILE);


      for(int i=0; i<scene_max; i++)
      {
        DrawAABox( sceneGL[i].x,
                sceneGL[i].y,
                sceneGL[i].z,
                10,10,10
                 );
      }

     glEndList();
```

DrawAABox draws 6 quad axis aligned box ( with glBegin glNormal GlVertexx... glEnd)
It work in immediate mode but when I try to build a disoplay list as above,
then call the list it has no effect (no boxes are drawed) Should it work or this just should  not work (I do not know much abut it )

Comment: For your question to be useful to others: Please include details that helped to find a solution by Rau. Otherwise it might get closed as *too localized* or *low quality*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A display list distills all OpenGL operations done inside the `glNewList/glEndList` block into a **constant** set of commands that are then executed when calling the display list (with `glCallList`). This means every *"dynamic"* code inside the list creation is, well, compiled into the list. So when called your box will use whatever position `sceneGL[i]` had when you built the list. In fact you will only have a constant number of boxes, that is whatever number `scene_max` was when building the list. So if you do this in initialization code, where `scene_max` might be `0`, nothing will be drawn.

Think about it, what could the driver possibly do when building this list? Just record all OpenGL commands called (and maybe convert them into some compressed and optimized format) for later submission or magically take the executed machine code (and its whole surrounding context) from your final executable when run and store this somehow to recall every operation you did between `glNewList/glEndList` (which wouldn't be much of a performance boost when compared to just executing it immediately, anyway)?

**EDIT:** As a side note, rather prefer the use of VBOs for *pre-recording* of geometry, which compared to display lists might loose some features, like state change recording, but give you others, like dynamic data updates. Likewise the implementation of display lists is totally up to the implementation and might not be faster than VBOs and the like. Likewise they're deprecated (which might also speak for lousy/slow implementations on modern hardware, because drivers don't tend to optimize rarely used paths that well).

Comment: Scene[] is properly initialised table, As I said this code works if is called immediate but Such way with displaylist this has no effect (other parts of scene (some terrain) are OK. So SHOULD it be working or not? -Ye it is dynamical but still should work maybe? Why it do not (Your answer was helpfull though)

Comment: maybe it is to large or somthing - I draw 1000 boxes so it is 6000 quads and 24 000 glVertex commands - IF it works the way you say - that it stores unvinded commands

Comment: It will only work if the scene you want to draw is properly set up when **constructing** the display list (as opposed to just calling it). If that is given (and you completely understood the answer), then yes, it should work. You can verify if it works by just subsituting your immediate mode code by the display list construction code **followed immediately** by calling the display list. If that doesn't work exactly like the immediate mode code, then your problem is most probably the one described in my answer, being that the display list **construction** happens at the wrong time.

Comment: Posting some more of your actual code might also help narrowing the problem. By the way, size shouldn't be that much of a problem. Although display lists can get quite large (and probably far larger than an equivalent vertex array/buffer), this should still be no problem in your case, I think. Also take note of *datenwolf*'s answer, especially the first part about not having a proper GL context yet.

Comment: This is ok I just have void doit() { KookBoxes(); DrawBoxes() }, where KookBoxes calls only once (on boolean flag inside) (And DrawBoxes is call list) So it is just the same cantext 100%. This in immediate works, with display list nothing appears on screen

Comment: @grungefightr And when the first time `doit` is called and thus `KookBoxes` is called all boxes are allready existing? You have to be totally sure about this. Maybe you accidentally/indirectly call `doit` before creating those boxes?

Comment: The wgl context is ok - I also draw other elements than it (the other in immediate) and it shows and it works ok, but just my other elements do not show when i put it into display list, rest OGL app works ok

Comment: @grungefightr So what is the definite answer to my last comment?

Comment: iou mean scene[[] table with its coordinates, yes it is okay for sure, When I just comment dislay list related lines in kook boxes so it goes int immediate is shows - so just enveloping it into displai list makes it wrong (invisible, do not shows)

Comment: so I thing it is related to this problem - WHAT CODE THAT WORKS IN IMMEDIATE WHEN ENVELOPED INTO DISPLAY LIST CAN STOOP WORKING (soorry for bigcase)

Comment: the only things I used down below the DrawAABox ale those: glBegin() glNormal() glVertex() and glEnd() - though its argument are calculated dynamically in for loop - (then stored in display list If I do understend how it should work)

Comment: @grungefightr And what happens if you, just for testing, call `KookBoxes` **each time** before `DrawBoxes`? Does that work?

Comment: tested, It sem to work :O Does it not overflows something ? (I do not delete lists)

Comment: If it do not overflows ( i call     glNewList(displist_boxy, GL_COMPILE); with the same displist_boxy id) still it is not intended to kook it before each call :/ what it could be? Something deletes it before draw?

Comment: Aaah! So it is probably as I guessed. The display list cooking itself works, but you're performing it at the wrong time. You probably (maybe just by accident) call `doit` at some point **before** your scene (or rather those boxes) is set up properly. So when `doit` is called the first time, you don't have your boxes yet. Thus the display list is compiled **with no boxes in it**. The standard approach to this is to reset your flag (the one checked in `KookBoxes`) whenever your scene changes, so that the display lists gets recreated the next time it is needed.

Comment: By the way, recreating the display list each time won't overflow anything, as it will just destroy whatever was in there before (only if you use the same ID, of course). But you're right in that recreation each time totally defeats the purpose of display lists. But like said above, just resetting a dirty-flag whenever the scene changes is the usual approach to this.

Comment: nay it does not working when i put my Kook() guard flag into :   "static int initialized = 0;  if(initialized > 100) return; initialized++;" Then I got the boxes in first 100 frames then it also vanishes - so it is other constand couse, Like something that destroys it (maybe some OGL  call destroys it?)

Comment: @me well not really, foun that if i put my glNewList in oglSetup (not in the later place do not know why, but foun this thip before in some other person troubles) Then I need do call Kook just 2 times !! (one call makes no result as I said but two calls are sufficient then it stays. GOD I will have to log things out, strange behaviour

Comment: @grungefightr And you also didn't accidentally reused the list ID (and thus overwrote it with some other unrelated list somewhere). Or maybe you didn't obtain it with `glGenLists` but later used `glGenLists` for another list (and of course OpenGL doesn't know you already used the generated list ID for your own purposes). But this is probably not the case, because every tutorial on display lists has teached you to always use `glGenLists` for generating display list IDs.

Comment: seem you have right - found that first time it is called with empty (0) list id - so there is some hidden pre-call to id, though i do not found yet its origin, muz tnx

Comment: ye, checked - it was becouse resizeGLWindow event was fired before my setupGl code - It not fired my code but seem that it cancels something in ogl state or something, I do not know exectli without spyin on it Just needed tu put conditional SetupGL in first lines of ResizeGL, gosh (will rething it later ) Now it kooks just with forst an only call theng works ok, Much tnx for help with that

Comment: I was disoriented becouse I was not sure if it should work at all and not sure where areas to search for bug, now after stating that it should work in such cases it will be much easier), tnx yet again

Answer (score 1):

You seem to miss generating of UID for `displist_boxy` variable. Here's how it should look.

```
coAxis := glGenLists(1);
glNewList(coAxis, GL_COMPILE);
  glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    ...
  glEnd;
glEndList;
```

Usage is as follows:

```
glCallList(coAxis);
```

Comment: I called it before, also rest of scene is working ok, and ogl is properly initialised, I write for OGL 1.3

Comment: You should include these details into your question next time.

Answer (score 1):

To create a display list, you must have your target OpenGL context being created and bound first. If you happen to initialize the display list in code that's called before there's a/the OpenGL context nothing will show up later.

Also what Christian Rau told you in https://stackoverflow.com/a/13192138/524368

On a side note: You should not be using Display lists at all. They've been deprecated for about 10 years (OpenGL-2 was originally planned to do away with display lists) and OpenGL-3 followed through to it a half a decade later.

Use VBOs and VAOs instead.

Comment: got not vbo it is ogl 1.3 I can use Vertex Array probably (It would be much more efficient?) But still would like to test display list also for knowledge

Comment: @grungefightr Wow, I hope that restriction to 15-20 year old hardware is not just artificial.

Comment: @ChristianRau: About 14 years old, but yes. OpenGL-1.3 had multitexturing, cube maps and an early set of register combiners. The first HW to support these were NVidia TNT2, but it got useful only with the very first GeForce GPUs.

Comment: @grungefightr: Display lists have go to the hardware somehow, too. And if your HW doesn't support VBOs, then display lists won't be able to put their data into VRAM as well. So plain vertex arrays and display would have about equal performance in your situation.

Comment: Ok but display list seem to be simpler for me than vertex arrays To make up Display list I just use about 4-5 short lines of added code

Comment: @grungefightr: Think it about this way: The geometry you want to draw is present in arrays in memory anyways. So why not simply use them directly instead of wasting time with thousands of function calls?